# String comparison in XSLT

Tags: xslt

When I call this template I get the following results.

```
155IT Matches 155OO
155OO Matches 155OO
155PP
```

The XML I am processing does have three rows and those are the values, but why is the test returning true for the first two and false for the last one? How should I be doing the string comparison?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template name="ProofOfConcept">
      <xsl:param name="Lines"/>
      <xsl:param name="MainDeliveryCode"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$Lines">
            <xsl:variable name="CurrentDeliveryCode" select="$Lines/DLVYLOCCD"/>
            <p>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=" $MainDeliveryCode = $CurrentDeliveryCode">
<xsl:value-of select="$CurrentDeliveryCode"/> Matches <xsl:value-of select="$MainDeliveryCode"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Lines"/> Fails <xsl:value-of select="$MainDeliveryCode"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            </p>
            <xsl:call-template name="ProofOfConcept">
                        <xsl:with-param name="Lines" select="$Lines[position() > 1]"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="MainDeliveryCode" select="$MainDeliveryCode"/>
                     </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:call-template name="ProofOfConcept">
                <xsl:with-param name="Lines" select="data/Lines/LINE"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="MainDeliveryCode" select="data/header/DLVYLOCCD"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample data

```
 <?xml version="1.0"
 encoding="ISO-8859-1"
 standalone="yes"?> <data>   
 <header><DLVYLOCCD>155OO</DLVYLOCCD>
 </header>    <Lines>
       <LINE><DLVYLOCCD>155IT</DLVYLOCCD></LINE>
       <LINE><DLVYLOCCD>155OO</DLVYLOCCD></LINE>
       <LINE><DLVYLOCCD>155PP</DLVYLOCCD></LINE>
</Lines> </data>
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Without seeing your input XML this is somewhat difficult to say. Please edit your post and include a sample input document.

Comment: In doing futher research I have discovered that the test is returning true so long as the correct value is ahead of the current position or it is the current position. Despite only the current value is displayed when I print the value.

Comment: To select the one matching `<LINE>` node (or nothing at all), the following XPath expression is enough: `/data/Lines/LINE[DLVYLOCCD = /data/header/DLVYLOCCD]`. No need to iterate or recurse *at all*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a less painful version of your XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <!-- this selects the matching LINE node(s), or nothing at all -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="
          Lines/LINE[DLVYLOCCD = /data/header/DLVYLOCCD]
        " />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="LINE">
    <p>
      <!-- for the sake of the example, just output a copy -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives (formatted result):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <LINE><DLVYLOCCD>155OO</DLVYLOCCD></LINE>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but I needed to stop on the first match. I should have specified.

Comment: @Jeremy: Why would you want to output the three "fails" before the match, but not the three after it? Or do you *actually* want to output the match only?

Comment: I actually want to output the match only. I was outputting the fails as a diagnostic until I could devise a way to stop at the correct one.

Comment: You must try to stop thinking about XSLT in an iterative/imperative way. It is a declarative programming language - you should never iterate until you have what you are looking for, but simply *select* what you are looking for. I'll change my answer accordingly.

Comment: Do you have a good reference for how to select that I could use in the future?

Comment: You would need to learn XPath. There are plenty of web pages that provide tutorials, and XPath isn't *that* hard actually.

Comment: For XSLT/XPATH 1.0 I found Evan Lenz's "XSLT 1.0 Pocket Reference" (O'Reilly) to be a really good, inexpensive tutorial.  It did a good job of communicating the essentials of declarative vs imperative style.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things wrong with your implementation. Most important, the expression:

```
<xsl:variable name="CurrentDeliveryCode" select="$Lines/DLVYLOCCD"/>
```

returns a node-set consisting of all the DLVYLOCCD elements, not just the current one as you seem to assume.  Also, you shouldn't be using recursion to iterate.  Use `<xsl:for-each>` instead, in which case you will process the items one at a time.

Comment: I used recusrion in this case because I need stop on the first match. The goal is to find the first address for a location print it and stop processing so that I don't print it more than once.

What expression would return just the current one?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I need to change my test to

```
<xsl:when test="contains($MainDeliveryCode, $CurrentDeliveryCode" >
```

That solved the problem.

http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_contains.html is the documentation for the function.

Comment: My recommendation would be to abandon your current XSLT and start over. ;) It might work, but the approach you take way to complicated and if it does not hurt you now, it will hurt you later.

Comment: Already did it after you showed me how to do it with selecting instead of recursion. I have even tested the new code with no loops and no recursion and it works perfectly.